# Disable scrolling throughout the device

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is any way, a piece of java code, in android to disable both the horizontal and vertical scrolling throughout the android device. I can disable the scrolling inside an app, but is there any way that my app triggers some device state change to prevent the scrolling in home, and other paths unless the app is closed from background.

Comment: I think you want to look at [Kiosk Mode](https://developers.google.com/android/management/policies/dedicated-devices) - either that solution or you can find apps that do it on standard phones. Just wanting to disable scrolling seems a funny restriction, though; you'll need to explain more about what you are trying to do, I think.

Comment: Kiosk mode is mostly used for presentation purposes. To run a fixed application and limiting or just removing all interactions from the phone. Like when the put one on the displays for people to use and test other features but not open other apps or install them